# How should I stop my aggressive cat from viciously attacking me?

Tags: cats, behavior, safety, aggression

My 2 year old, male, part Egyptian Mau cat is really vicious when he attacks. There is always blood after it has happened. What can I do to stop him?

He will attack any part of you and he always inflicts bleeding wounds. He also goes for my dog too, but not to the extent he does while attacking me.

Comment: I think more information would help people answer the question.  Such as, is the cat neutered, and is there some sort of pattern or circumstances that precede an attack?

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. Without understanding **why** your cat attacks you, we cannot help you **stop** these attacks. Please [edit] your post and describe in which situation(s) your cat attacks you and how both you and he act right befor such an attack. Especially his body posture is important. Does he stare at you with big, round eyes? Is his tail raised and bushy? Are his ears facing forward or laid flat against the skull?